# schema dilema, is neo4j the right choice

Tags: sql, graph, neo4j, schema

I want to create the following schema
User <-> Tag <-> Content -> SubContent <-> User

There are **many-to-many** connections between *user* and *tag*

There are **many-to-many** connections between *tag* and *content*

There is **one-to-many** connections between *content* and *subcontent*

There are **many-to-many** connections between *subcontent* and *user*

So there is a lot of connections here, Thats why I thought that neo4j would be a right choice.

My main queries would be to get the relationships of certain tags 
and access subcontent that is connected to certain users.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a graph db, and neo4j in particular, would be ideally suited.  Having the multiple many-to-many relationships, and given how you are planning on 'browsing' the data are really in the graphdb sweet spot.

Answer (score 1):

Fully agree with Dan G. A Graph db and Neo4j makes sense here. I have a very similar domain model and it feels like "cheating" everytime i query for something (coming from SQL). Also adding properties to the relationship themselfs can add extra info, like "stength" or "amount" on the content CONTAINS subcontent relationship.

Also "future proof" architecture if you would like to add something else in the future like SIMILARTY relationship between tags.